# Multiple Children in one DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can I add two elements to an DataTemplate which is inside                     ItemsControl.ItemTemplate ?
I need something like this:

```
...
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid/>
    <TextBlock/>
  </DataTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
...
```

I want to add a Textblock to my existing DataTemplate, but this DataTemplate already contains a Grid.

What I want to reach:
I want to add a Textblock to my Grid when the which represents the definition of my Row number.
In the MainViewModel is a ObservableCollection LineNumberList which should bind to this Textblock.

My MainView:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MachineList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="False"
                              gridhelper:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                              gridhelper:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}"
                              gridhelper:GridHelpers.StarColumns="0,1,2,3,4">
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="200"
                              Height="200">
                            <Image  Style="{StaticResource ImageMachine}" />
                            <Grid ShowGridLines="True"
                                  Style="{StaticResource SubGridMachine}" />
                        </Grid>

                        <TextBlock "WHICH I NEED HERE" 
                            Grid.Row="{Binding LineNumberList}"
                            Grid.Column"0"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                                Value="{Binding LineNumber}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                                Value="{Binding StationNumber}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
```

My MainViewModel:

```
 #region Variables Lists
    public ObservableCollection<Machine> MachineList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Head> HeadList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> LineNumberList { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public int RowCount { get; set; } = 10;
    public int ColumnCount { get; set; } = 5;
    public CreateMachineCommand CreateMachineCommand { get; set; }
    public DeleteMachineCommand DeleteMachineCommand { get; set; }




    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MachineList = new ObservableCollection<Machine>();
        HeadList = new ObservableCollection<Head>();
        LineNumberList = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        CreateMachineCommand = new CreateMachineCommand(this);
        DeleteMachineCommand = new DeleteMachineCommand(this);
        ReadMachineFromDB();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a StackPanel and have your Grid and TextBlock inside it.

```xml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Width="200"
                      Height="200">
                    <Image  Style="{StaticResource ImageMachine}" />
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True"
                            Style="{StaticResource SubGridMachine}" />
                </Grid>

                <TextBlock "WHICH I NEED HERE" 
                    Grid.Row="{Binding LineNumberList}"
                    Grid.Column"0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This is not working.
The Textbox gets in the same cell like the grid.
But the textbox needs to be always in Grid.Column="0"